# Why does localization work incorrectly at Django 1.11?

Tags: django, django-models

I translate the names of the application into `Russian`. But I do not understand why some applications are translated, while others are not. Here is an example.

*This does not work:*

```
#: donation/apps.py:9
msgid "Donation"
msgstr "Донат"
```

*This works:*

```
#: reputation/apps.py:9
msgid "Reputation"
msgstr "Репутация"
```

**donation/apps**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from django.apps import AppConfig


class DonationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'donation'
    verbose_name = _('Donation')
```

**reputation/apps**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from django.apps import AppConfig


class ReputationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'reputation'
    verbose_name = _('Reputation')
```

**settings**

```
# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('ru', gettext('Russian')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    path('locale'),
)
```

template

```
<div class="app-donation module">
        <table>
        <caption>
            <a href="/admin/donation/" class="section" title="Модели в приложении Donation">Donation</a>
        </caption>

            <tr class="model-projectfriend">

                <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/donation/projectfriend/">Project Friends</a></th>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/projectfriend/add/" class="addlink">Добавить</a></td>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/projectfriend/" class="changelink">Изменить</a></td>

            </tr>

            <tr class="model-projectrelease">

                <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/donation/projectrelease/">Project Releases</a></th>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/projectrelease/add/" class="addlink">Добавить</a></td>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/projectrelease/" class="changelink">Изменить</a></td>

            </tr>

            <tr class="model-projectdonation">

                <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/donation/projectdonation/">Project donations</a></th>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/projectdonation/add/" class="addlink">Добавить</a></td>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/projectdonation/" class="changelink">Изменить</a></td>

            </tr>

            <tr class="model-releasetask">

                <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/donation/releasetask/">Release Tasks</a></th>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/releasetask/add/" class="addlink">Добавить</a></td>



                <td><a href="/admin/donation/releasetask/" class="changelink">Изменить</a></td>

            </tr>

        </table>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `('ru', gettext_lazy('Russian')),` ?

Comment: @nik_m yes. This does not work.

Comment: where do you see the translations? which template is rendered?

Comment: In this template, there are no strings marked for translations, neither any variables. You should show us the source of the template. Not the rendered one!

Comment: Added the `Donation` template. That's what I noticed. I try to just change the name of the application in `donation / apps.py` (` verbose_name = _ ('ABC') `) - does not change ...

Comment: @nik_m How I can do you show the source? This is the admin page ...

Comment: then tell us which view it is, is it the list view of some specific model? or which part of the admin site?

Comment: @dirkgroten this is a main page of the admin site ( `/admin/` ).

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm added screen

Comment: @dirkgroten `Reputation` and `Donation` are 2 applications. The main folder is called `midgard` (it contains various _settings_, _static_ etc). There is a folder with the translation (`locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`).

Comment: then the answer below will help, because your translations are not inside *locale* directory in each app, but in the main app folder. your `LOCALE_PATHS` is wrong. It should be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'midgard', 'locale')`,

Comment: Can you show where 'Reputation' is translated? You're sure it's in the title of the table (the blue background)?

Comment: @dirkgroten Everything is much simpler. The thing is my carelessness and lack of knowledge. The app (`Donation`)has not been defined in the \_\_init__ file in this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app (`Donation`) has not been defined in the `__init__` file in this application.

```
default_app_config = 'donation.apps.DonationConfig'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix `LOCALE_PATHS` to point to the actual path. This is not a [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path) used for urls, but an actual path, like `"/home/user/path/to/locale/dir"`.

What I use in my projects is this:

```
# settings.py

def here(*path):
    return join(abspath(dirname(__file__)), *path)


PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")  # adjust here if your settings.py is nested more


def root_is(*path):
    return join(abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *path)


ROOT = root_is  # ROOT("") == project root
```

The above is declared at the top of my `settings.py` file. Then, if I want to refer to a directory path (such a `LOCALE_PATHS`) I do this:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    ROOT('path/to/locale'),
)
```

If you want to use the conventional format that Django uses by default (`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`), then you may use:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    ROOT(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale")),
)
```

Make sure that you `print` these variables first, to ensure that paths are correct.

Comment: Thnx. Everything is much simpler. The thing is my carelessness and lack of knowledge. The app (`Donation`)has not been defined in the \_\_init__ file in this application.

Comment: Good for you! Glad it worked. You should probably answer your own question and marked it as accepted in order for others to quickly find the answer to this question. Cheers!!!